# State transition Analysis Technique

Tags: ids, intrusion

As far as I have read and understood [STAT](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/IDS/2000_vigna_eckmann_kemmerer_discex00.pdf?w=AADRtkz8FQPXLExgnM_cbZewv183Pi3onskwJ2ZbZWSn_A&disable_range=1&convert_doc_to_pdf=1) is a concept used to design a platform independent IDS.

My question is whether there exists any compiler/interpreter for STAT Language as I am planning to do a project on IDS. My team was reading through some related articles and we actually couldn't find any method to implement STAT or use it practically.

Or is it like we just use this language in the design part and coding is to be done in any high-level languages?